# execute() function is not being executed when called

Tags: python, arrays, keyboard, keyevent

I am trying to make a **keymap** for my keyboard to not use **Microsofts** *useless* `IME keyboard`.
So I wrote this `python` code with `pynput`.

But it doesn't seem to **execute** my `execute()` function

> ```
>    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
>    
>    current = set()
>    keyboard_typ = Controller()
>    
>    COMBINATIONS = [
>    
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="q")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="Q")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="w")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="W")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="e")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="E")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="r")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="R")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="t")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="T")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="y")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="Y")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="u")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="U")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="i")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="I")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="o")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="O")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="p")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="P")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="a")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="A")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="s")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="S")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="d")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="D")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="f")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="F")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="g")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="G")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="h")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="H")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="j")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="J")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="k")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="K")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="l")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="L")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="z")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="Z")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="x")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="X")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="c")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="C")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="v")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="V")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="b")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="B")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="n")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="N")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="m")},
>        {keyboard.KeyCode(char="M")},
>    
>    ]
>    
>    def on_press(key) :
>    
>        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
>            current.add(key)
>            if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
>                execute()
>    
>    def execute() :
>    
>        if current == "q":
>            
>            print("q")
>        
>    
>    def on_release(key) :
>    
>        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
>            current.remove(key)
>    
>    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener :
>        listener.join()
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute() has `current` but you never pass such variable to the function, so you are comparing nothing. Your function should look like this

```
   def execute(current) :
   
       if current == "q":
           
           print("q")
```

Comment: in your if (`if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS)`) you are calling `execute()` but the function is empty as well, pass the variable you want to check and it should work

Comment: `def on_press(key) :

    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute(current)

def execute(word) :

    if word == "q":
        
        print("q")` this does not work

Comment: Even if I put the `if` condition in the `on_press` function where it is currently written `execute()` it does not work

Comment: if you pass `current` as variable in the if statement it won't work since you are passing a set instead of a string

Comment: `key` is what you are trying to check, right?

Comment: Yes I am looking for the key

Comment: Use `key` instead of `current`

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about Joaquín's "set to string" theory I converted my `set` to a `string`
and it worked.

Thnx Joaquín.

```
def execute(current_key) :
    s = str(current_key)
    for i in s :
        if i == "q" :
            print("q")
            #print("\bㅂ") I tested it with a language and it types the normal text too so I prefer adding\b before the letter/word/sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `current` to the function, it will have all the keys pressed now and use loop or if condition to check the key in pressed keys. or just pass the `key` if you need only the last key pressed.

```
def on_press(key) :

   if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
       current.add(key)
       if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
           execute(current)

def execute(current_key_set) :
   for key in current_key_set:
      print(key)
```

or

```
def on_press(key) :

   if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
       current.add(key)
       if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
           execute(key)

def execute(current_key) :
   print(current_key)
```

Comment: It works Thnx. just had to change the parameter from current to something else

Comment: But when the set has more than 2 keys it throws an error

Comment: But it still throws an error when it has more than 1 keys